# android sdk incompatiblities with wi-fi direct

Tags: android, android-intent, wifi-direct

I'm developing an app that uses wi-fi direct module. As you all know it's not available before Android 4.0, but I want to mantain compatibility without wi-fi direct.

The problem is I'm using instance variables from classes like Channel or WifiP2pManager. Of course on prior versions to ICS they'll not be available. I was just following the Android official developer guide, so It seemed that I did nothing wrong.

Any ideas of how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if(Build.VERSION_CODES < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
>     // compat code here
> } else {
>   // normal code here
> }
> ```

Comment: I now that, but I mean on an instance variable. I have a ClassNotFoundException just when it's created

Comment: you can find it here: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

Comment: It's the official docmentation and it just assign the values to instance variables. But, of course, this throws an Exception

Comment: It was not a problem with this. It was a problem with Roboguice =)

Answer (score 0):

Make your code conditional, like

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES. ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH ) {

  // something

}
```

or set minSdk version in your manifest

```
android:minSdkVersion="14"
```

or, if you need so, split your apps into separate modules, make core not requiring API14 but trying to use wifi-direct module. And wifi-direct module would require API14 so user with proper device would be able to install both, while others just the core.

Comment: Same as above: I now that, but I mean on an instance variable. I have a ClassNotFoundException just when it's created

Answer (score 0):

It was not a problem with this. It was a problem with Roboguice =)

I've just opened an issue. Just if someone wants to try it =)

http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/issues/detail?id=226&thanks=226&ts=1353421889